# Recover from phishing and being a good citizen

Tags: internet-security, phishing

There is a mail floating around which claims that someone you know wants to share a document with you and once you follow the link in the mail you get to a site that asks your google (or others) credentials then once the unsuspecting aunt enters the credentials all her contacts receive the same email and as though that is not enough, a filter is added to gmail which deletes every incoming email.

My sisters fall for that trap so I changed their passwords and removed the filters. anything else I should do?

Also I wish there was some resource that I could point all the people that might have been infected, which explain how to undo the damage - but I could not find any.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of many articles that you can suggest they read.

http://sites.udel.edu/phishing/2013/09/09/phishing-scam-targets-google-docs/

There is ample documentation on such exploits;  you don't need to report it anywhere at this point.

Teach your relatives to not click on links in emails, even if they are from people they "know"!

Comment: I wish there was a one stop place where you can find exactly what damage control to do. for example it is possible that the attack used "Recover Password" on ebay, amazon etc and stored these passwords and then deleted from gmail the mail evidences. so it is also advisable to change password for all your sites that use the gmail as user name.